# What the main differences as well as pros and cons behind the grammars for ggplot2 vs vega?

Tags: r, ggplot2, statistics, visualization, vega

[Vega](http://goo.gl/92Xuf) and [ggplot2](http://ggplot2.org/)  use different underlying grammars, and Hadley has stated that "It is likely to converge over time as both vega and gg2v become more mature, but there's no expectation that ggplot2 and gg2v will ever be exactly concordances. It's probably easier to think of gg2v as an alternative specification and rendering of the graphics DSL defined by ggplot2" http://goo.gl/rWzLTe

But what exactly are the main pros and cons in using one vs. the other?

Comment: Does vega produce javascript interactive graphics ?

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent I think your answer has to do with the underlying technology, but my question was about the implications of the actual grammar that serves as the basis for each of them. For example, ggplot2 is broadly based on [Wilkinson's Grammar of Graphics](http://www.amazon.com/The-Grammar-Graphics-Statistics-Computing/dp/0387245448)